# How to hide a field in node display if it's value is 0. Drupal 7.

Tags: drupal-7

I am using a drupal installation as a REST server for an Android application.  I store data in nodes and occasionally a field is blank, for example a location that has no phone number.  I had to standardize the JSON coming out of the drupal REST server to a specified class, so I was forced to add 0, as the value in the field.. Works great in Andriod, but when viewed on the drupal site, it looks bad..

So question is, if the value of the field is 0, Id like to change it to 
'None'.

I could do this in D6 with cck, but i dont know d7 field api.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) file, in the [field.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7) file or with the **[template_preprocess_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) function** (recommended) and with so many other options with an if statement. 
See an [example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30063/how-to-print-fields-in-node-tpl-php) for first template and one for [second option with the preprocess function](http://www.digett.com/blog/01/18/2012/change-output-single-field-drupal-7-node).

If you don't want to edit tpl.php files or you don't have access to the template.php file of your theme you can use the [Field formatter conditions](https://drupal.org/project/ffc) module that allows you to do this condition. Alternatives are [Custom Formatters](https://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) and [field_formatter_css_class](https://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class).

Comment: But unfortunately, the Field formatter conditions module only examines OTHER fields to compare to.  What I need is to reflect on the same field.  I'll check out the other options.